# Where To Put AngularJS Directive-Template Functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If I do something like this in my directive:

```
template: '<button ng-click="Done()">DONE</button>'
```

Then where do I put my $scope.Done() function? I have it in a controller here but that doesn't seem to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div mydiv></div>

        <script>
            angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.Done = function() {
                    alert('Done');
                };
            });

            angular.module("myApp", [])
            .directive("mydiv", function() {
                return {
                    template: '<button ng-click="Done()">DONE</button>'
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to edit your title with "SOLVED" or similar. Marking the accepted answer is all you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something like this will serve your purpose. Give a try ..

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
            .directive("mydiv", function() {
                return {
                    template: '<button ng-click="Done()">DONE</button>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.Done = function () {
                         alert('Done');
                    }
            }
                };
            });
```

Remove below fuction from controller.

```
 $scope.Done = function() {
                    alert('Done');
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not good approach to set the function directly, you need to bind it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div mydiv on-done="Done()"></div>

        <script>
            angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.Done = function() {
                    alert('Done');
                };
            });

            angular.module("myApp", [])
            .directive("mydiv", function() {
                return {
                    scope: {
                        onDone: '&'
                    },
                    template: '<button ng-click="onDone()">DONE</button>'
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/17585/